# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't resolve property name 'KPI' from 'Property set for bean

Tags: java, vaadin-grid

I'm trying to set column names for Vaadin grid component. The code is as below:

```
Grid<ClientInformation> clientInfoGrid = new Grid<>(ClientInformation.class);

clientInfoGrid.setColumns("KPI", "clientsLastYear", "clientsLastMonth", "clientsCurrentMonth",
                        "percentageMoM", "percentageYoY");
```

And ClientInformation class has these variables mentioned.

```
String KPI;
String clientsLastYear;
String clientsLastMonth;
String clientsCurrentMonth;
HorizontalLayout percentageMoM;
HorizontalLayout percentageYoY;
ClientInformation(String KPI,String clientsLastYear,String clientsLastMonth,String clientsCurrentMonth,
        HorizontalLayout percentageMoM,HorizontalLayout percentageYoY)
{
    this.KPI=KPI;
    this.clientsLastYear=clientsLastYear;
    this.clientsLastMonth=clientsLastMonth;
    this.clientsCurrentMonth=clientsCurrentMonth;
    this.percentageMoM=percentageMoM;
    this.percentageYoY=percentageYoY;
}
```

EDIT: format

Answer (score 1):

Check your getters and setters, specifically the one you use to get/set the KPI. The getters and setters will be used to determine the properties, not the member variable names. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html

Comment: Error is gone after getters and setters and after adding lines like below
clientInfoGrid.addColumn(ClientInformation::getKPI).setHeader("KPI");
But table not displaying yet

Comment: @DattaDhonde that is a different problem. You should create a new Question with enough information to determine what is happening.